# In flutter "After clicking create account, the part that comes is a web interface. How do you get a customized design exactly like the design? "

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

After clicking Create an account, the part that comes is a web interface(it's coming from the website). How do you get a customized design?
[create an account screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txKF0.png)

[web view container screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjHpe.png)

I need to make the custom web view like this for the this container
[web view container screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYoKr.png)